# What are the best practices for releasing an open source project?

Tags: open-source, release, release-management

We have a pretty cool little web framework that we have used successfully on dozens of client projects. We are planning to release this software to the community. However, I am wringing my hands about what should/should-not go on a new open source software project page. What are the things the site must have? Docs? A Wiki? A link to download? What else?

And, a related but possibly different question is how do we begin marking release numbers. All we use internally is the SVN stamp. Is there a good way to determine when to start calling something version 0.9 versus 1.0 and 1.1 and so-on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get an idea of what's required by what open source project hosting sites provide:

- A web site which acts as the "one stop shop" for the project
- Docs, potentially in wiki form
- A source repository allowing browsing, anonymous checkout, and authenticated and authorised commits
- Issue tracking and new feature requests

As for version numbers... I don't think *anyone's* worked out the best way of doing that yet :) With a bare minimum of thought, I'd consider:

- v1.0 should be ready for production use
- Major version number changes can completely lose backward compatibility (if necessary - hardly a goal though!)
- Minor version number changes should usually be mostly compatible - deprecating is probably better than removing/renaming bits of API
- Smaller-than-minor version number changes should only include minor functional additions (if any) and bug/performance fixes

Answer (score 2):

On versioning, I think the absolute best place to start from is [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org).

Answer (score 1):

The 0.9 / 1.0 / 1.1 / 1.0.1 / ... version labelling is for marketing purpose only (in the good sense of it). This allows your users/customers to identify if the release is major, minor or bug-fix and whether you consider it mature or not yet.

The minimum to deliver is sources. Other deliverables depend on how you are willing to help your users and provide them support.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a website to host the source on first (SourceForge, for example). Get the source up there on a version control system with anonymous checkout. Get an email address on there for people to contact you.

Call this first version 0.1. This is because you don't have docs yet to support the project.

Then breathe.

Then start looking at documentation, like a wiki.  Once you have it all covered, at a basic level of detail, and you believe the release is ready for some primetime, then move to 1.0, and start providing binary downloads.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you think about the license for the sources.

When I look at an open source project, one of the first things I check is the license. If the license is not GPL2/GPL3/BSD styles or similar, that's a demotivator for me.

The license means what people will do with it, how it can grow, and how much it is owned by the corporate who released it. As by choosing open source I try not to depend on corporations (who depend on their share holders), I really choose to use the software that is really free.

As the open source community is very sensitive to corporate power (Google seems a bit immune to that at the moment), so you really must make sure to deliver the message of **truly free** on your web site and other materials you release about the software.

See more on [free software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) and [open source](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/open-source-misses-the-point.html) definitions of the FSF.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at GitHub or Google Code. they provide a very good starting point for own open source projects. You can describe your project, documentate in a wiki, use git or svn as your repository, and provide downloads together with an issue tracking and multi-developer management. Nice environments out of the box to learn from and to use them.

For release numbers: I don't recommend 0.9 or something like this for pre-releases. The reason? What about release 1.9? Is it the 9th sub-release of the major release 1 or is it the last pre-release of release 2? My release standard is decribed here: http://code.google.com/p/tideland-eas/wiki/ReleaseStandard. I'm using a three-number-scheme, major, minor, and fix, together with a status code, alpha, beta, gamma, and the release date. So I'm able to handle multiple releases in parallel easily.

Hope this helps.

mue